# Azure Servicebus Completed Messages Metric - AVG, Count, Max... why is Count wrong?

Tags: azure, servicebus

I sent 100 messages, they all completed, but Count is showing incorrect value while Max and AVG total to 100.

I'm trying to understand the aggregation chart for service bus topic messages. The values for `completed messages` `Max` and `Avg` are correct and total to 100, but `Count` is 0 or 1.

Time granularity is 1m.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

your image has no issue. In your first snip show 100 income message. and in second(46) and third(54) image 46+54=100 message complete.

I reproduce this, and no any glitch was found.
[image]

Active Messages
[image]

First Output is correct as data values.
[image]

Second output is also correct as data values.
[image]

In this output, show 100 Income Messages but show Outgoing Messages is 0.
[image]

After clicking on the arrow icon, its show 0 incoming message, and 100 outgoing messages.
[image]

Azure Monitoring shows a chart base on values and their time. if the difference between time and values so some values may be not shown but you can view these values by clicking on right and left arrow icons.

Comment: My question is regarding the COUNT aggregation showing 0.